# Polymer styling :host[attribute] failed

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, polymer, web-component

Got simple component with `faded` attribute.

```
 <template>
      <style>
            :host {
                display: block;
                height: 7em;
                background: white;
                border: 1px solid var(--paper-blue-grey-50);
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0.1em 0;
            }
            :host ([faded]) {
                display: none;
                background: #eaeaea;
                color: #a8a8a8;
                cursor: auto;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            .month {
                ...
            }
            .names {
               ...
            }
            .date {
                ...
            }
        </style>

        <div>
            <div class="month" hidden="[[hideMonth]]">[[details.month]]</div>
            <div class="names">
                <span class="date">[[details.date]]</span>
                <div hidden="[[hideName]]">
                    <div>[[details.name]]</div>
                    <div class="highlight annotation"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </template>

    <script>
        'use strict';
        Polymer({
            is: "calendar-day-short-view",
            properties: {
                date: {
                    type: Object,
                    observer: '_dayChanged'
                },
                details: {
                    type: Object,
                    value: function () {
                        return {}
                    }
                },
                hideMonth: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    reflectToAttribute: true,
                    value: false
                },
                hideName: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    reflectToAttribute: true,
                    value: false
                },
                holiday: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    reflectToAttribute: true,
                    value: false
                },
                faded: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    reflectToAttribute: true,
                    value: false
                }
            },
            _dayChanged: function () {
                var cal = new Calendar();
                cal.date = this.date;
                this.details = {
                    date: this.date.getDate(),
                    name: cal.getDayName(),
                    day: this.date.getDay(),
                    month: cal.getMonthName()
                };
            }
        })
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

Unfortunately it renders only `:host` style and ignores `:host[faded]`, when I try to include the component into another one like this:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[week]]">
<calendar-day-short-view date="[[item]]" class="flex" hide-month faded></calendar-day-short-view>
</template>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have it wrong on both counts. The correct selector to use is `:host([faded])`.

- `:host ([faded])` is not a valid selector. The space needs to be dropped, because [CSS forbids having whitespace between a function name and its accompanying parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13877198/why-is-rgb-224-226-213-an-invalid-property-value/13877218#13877218). Furthermore, [parentheses are not allowed in a selector *except* when part of a recognized function token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5478920/are-parentheses-allowed-in-css-selectors/5478943#5478943).
- `:host[faded]` is grammatically sound, but it won't work because the shadow host is [featureless](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#featureless), and therefore cannot be matched by attribute selectors in that context (i.e. when *compounded* with the `:host` pseudo). This is why a functional variant is provided for `:host` in the form of `:host()`, so you can match the host element against a specific compound selector while still dealing with this restriction.

Comment: I didn't realize the difference between `:host` and `:host()`. Specifically though, this works both ways with Polymer, because it replaces the `:host[faded]` selector with `x-foo[faded]` or whatever. So that it's backwards compatible with other browsers I assume. Here've an example: http://jsbin.com/zusayu/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @Tomasz Pluskiewicz: Huh, I didn't realize Polymer did that. I'd consider that a bug, since that behavior is not according to spec. In fact, [css-scoping has an example comparing the two](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#host-selector), and it states quite plainly that the compound selector is supposed to match nothing, whereas the functional (not compounded) variant will work.